# Multiple selected box value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have this link [multiple selection](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/index.proto.html). I have looked at multiple selection examples. I want exactly the same logic in my `html` view. Can you please tell me some simple logic for this multiple selection? Please, help!

I did not get the `js` code that they have used.

Comment: Use `multiple` attribute of select....something like `<select multiple>`

Comment: Have you seen that link? In that Mutiple select exmple. I want that logic.I did not get How I use logic  near java script

Comment: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen take a look here, you can access all the code used.

Comment: @Zeratops I think my quetion is like silly but, I had download the sorce,I want only that multiple select part code but, I did not get the code part.please help.

Comment: @Pratiksha I am having problem understanding you...Can you be more clear...I suppose you want to achieve same thing using ONLY javascript.., although same can be achieved with HTML...

Comment: Yes @Rakesh_Kumar I have that link. In that link exmple 'Multiple select .....Turn this.....into this...' But,In there code I did not get found code for only that multiple select.I want that code to use in my html page  or if simple logic like same that code?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar You getting my question?

Comment: @Pratiksha the code you are searching for is going to do what??...Some thing like `Into This` select type is implemented `?

Comment: Exactly Yes near INTO THIS :-)

Comment: Thnx that you have to approch my question i.e what I exactly want :-) pls help!

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Pls help!

Comment: @Pratiksha Stuck in my work..Sorry! I will do now..

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Its ok. I will wait.

Comment: Have you free or working on?

Comment: @Pratiksha I have made a basic one..Take a look.If you can take it up from there, it will be good and an exercise too.. ;) http://jsfiddle.net/0gka9aj9/1/

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar ;-)  but format is not set and cancel in not work..pls see once..?

Comment: @Pratiksha A more updated one http://jsfiddle.net/0gka9aj9/2/ ...Surely you have to try something on your own..you might be having more clarity about requirements than me...

Comment: your code is good work! but like in that multiselect view can we do it same in div view and cancel and etc. so,It will looks good right?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Yes ! but :-) I will try to myself too ;-)! ok.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Pls just tell me the function for remove selected if does not want...just tell me this much I willl do my self other fucntion in that

Comment: Clicking on close icon button will help in removing items....`removefromlist` function is doing that..

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar but Its not work. pls help. my last point in project task to do today only.I tryid much things but not works. So,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72046/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-pratiksha).